# When an element is clicked, the text for all elements is changed, not just the target text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, so I apologise if this is a really stupid question.

I have added a click event to the Person component.

When clicked, I only want the target name to change.

The problem is, is that when clicked the name is changed on all 4 elements, and not just the target.

I assume the error is very obvious, but having never really used React until today, I would have no idea where to start!

Here is `People.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './People.css';

import Person from "../Person/Person"
import '../Person/Person.css'

class People extends Component {

  state = {
    persons: [
      {name: "Theresa", age: 65, location: "London"},
      {name: "Matthew", age: 45, location: "Birmingham"},
      {name: "Jeremy", age: 56, location: "Norwich"},
      {name: "Vince", age: 78, location: "Oxford"}
    ]
  }

  personClickHandler = (newName) => {

    console.log(newName)

    this.setState({
      persons: [
        {name: newName, age: 65, location: "London"},
        {name: newName, age: 45, location: "Birmingham"},
        {name: newName, age: 56, location: "Norwich"}
        {name: newName, age: 72, location: "Oxford"}
      ]
    })

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="People">

        <Person
          className="Person"
          name={this.state.persons[0].name}
          age="24"
          location="Leigh-on-Sea, Essex"
          click={this.personClickHandler.bind(this, "Boris")}
        />

        <Person
          className="Person"
          name={this.state.persons[1].name}
          age="22"
          location="Westcliff-on-Sea, Essex"
          click={this.personClickHandler.bind(this, "Jacob")}
        />

        <Person
          className="Person"
          name={this.state.persons[2].name}
          age="18"
          location="Thundersley, Essex"
          click={this.personClickHandler.bind(this, "Kier")}
        />

        <Person
          className="Person"
          name={this.state.persons[3].name}
          age="51"
          location="Orange County, California"
          click={this.personClickHandler.bind(this, "Lucy")}
        />

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default People
```

And here is `Person.js`

```
import React from 'react'

const Person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div 
        onClick={props.click}
        className="Person">
            <h2>{props.name}</h2>
            <p>{props.age}</p> 
            <p>{props.location}</p> 
      </div>
    )

}

export default Person
```

Comment: I believe all text changes because you are selecting the className Person so any element with that class name set is going to get the changes. Someone with more react experience can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dvo : It is not because of className, className just applies css, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @norrisollie: You are setting the name property of every person in your state to newName, whereas you should be only setting the selected element's name.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `personClickHandler` you set all four names to be the same `newName`. You need to only change one of the names.

You'll have a much easier time doing this if you move your state onto each individual `Person` rather than having your state managed by a container class.

You could also use something like..

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="People">
      {this.state.persons.map( ( person, index ) => {
        return <Person
          key={index}
          className="Person"
          name={person.name}
          age={person.age}
          location={person.location} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

..so that you don't have to type so much manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a most proficient solution but you can do something like this in order to fill the purpose

```
 personClickHandler = newName => {
console.log(newName);
if (newName === "Lucy") {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: "Theresa", age: 65, location: "London" },
      { name: "Matthew", age: 45, location: "Birmingham" },
      { name: "Jeremy", age: 56, location: "Norwich" },
      { name: newName, age: 78, location: "Oxford" }
    ]
  });
} else if (newName === "Boris") {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: newName, age: 65, location: "London" },
      { name: "Matthew", age: 45, location: "Birmingham" },
      { name: "Jeremy", age: 56, location: "Norwich" },
      { name: "Vince", age: 78, location: "Oxford" }
    ]
  });
} else if (newName === "Jacob") {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: "Theresa", age: 65, location: "London" },
      { name: newName, age: 45, location: "Birmingham" },
      { name: "Jeremy", age: 56, location: "Norwich" },
      { name: "Vince", age: 78, location: "Oxford" }
    ]
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    persons: [
      { name: "Theresa", age: 65, location: "London" },
      { name: "Matthew", age: 45, location: "Birmingham" },
      { name: newName, age: 56, location: "Norwich" },
      { name: "Vince", age: 78, location: "Oxford" }
    ]
  });
}
```

};